# AngularJS/Bootstrap never sees changes to service object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning angular - I have an application that via ajax loads some information about a current web app user's account.

The problem is that I'm using an angular/bootstrap modal which never seems to know when then user accounts results came in. Standard templates work fine, they refresh when the user account data changes. I'm not sure if it's an issue with modals or if I'm organizing the code incorrectly.

I have a factory/service for `userAccount` which stores the current user info.

An ajax request grabs the user info, so obviously there's a slight delay:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'api/url'}).success(function(resp, status, headers, config){
  if( resp.results ){
    userAccount.user = resp.results;
  }
});
```

My root application controller watches this value for changes and assigns it the scope among other required actions:

```
$scope.$watch( function(){return userAccount;}, function(newUser,oldUser){
  $scope.user = newUser.user;
}, true);
```

I have a route/controller setup for `#/account` that allows me to directly link people to their account modal. However, the modal opens at a point when the user account data hasn't been returned, and the `userAccount` information never changes. To test I added a `watch` to the account controller itself, and the event only fired once on load.

If I open the modal after the user ajax, it all works fine. It's as if the modal gets a copy of the `userAccount` object, not a reference to the original.

```
.controller('AccountController', function ($scope, $modal, $http, userAccount) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'modules/modal/account.tpl.html',
        controller: ['$scope', '$http', 'userAccount', function ($scope, $http, userAccount) {
            $scope.keys = userAccount.user.keys;
            // Never alerted to changes for userAccount, even if watching.

        }]
    });
})
```

Per comments, the route I'm using for the modal:

```
.config(function($stateProvider){
  $stateProvider
    .state('account', {
      url: "/account",
      views: {
        "modal": {
          template: '',
          controller: 'AccountController'
        }
      },
      data:{ pageTitle: 'My Account' }
    });
})
```

Any help or advice on something I'm not doing correctly within angular is appreciated.

Comment: What is route set up?

Comment: @dfsq Added the route config to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare objects for equality as the reference of userAccount hasn't changed. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope
So, do

```
$scope.$watch( function(){return userAccount;}, function(newUser,oldUser){
  $scope.user = newUser.user;
}, true);
```

Comment: I didn't include it in my example, sorry - but I am doing this. I'll update it

Comment: @helion3 As, per the controller and `$http` request code, `userAccount` doesn't exist on scope.To place a watch on it, it must exist on the respective scope.

Comment: I'm marking your answer as accepted because while I *did* have the second `watch` argument in my main app, I wasn't using it when I tested the watch in the modal controller. Adding that argument to a second `watch` statement to the modal controller resolves the issue.